# Is it correct to say "greedy little mind" or "little greedy mind" or both?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

I was watching ERB, and Tesla replied to Thomas Edison - "You couldn't handle my gifts with your greedy little mind".

What if I say: "little greedy mind", what does it change on the meaning. Is it right to say?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Greedy little mind" would be much more idiomatic. "Little greedy mind" would imply that Edison was small-minded as well as greedy.

Comment: In English, "little" can be a pure value judgment without denotative meaning at all. What one Oxford philosopher called "con-ish" (as opposed to "pro-ish"). You could replace it with a raspberry or by spitting and no information would be lost. The drill sergeant could call a seven-foot recruit "you 'orrible little man" and no one would bat an eyelid. So if you call someone a "greedy little mind" it carries only the meanings that (a) you are greedy and (b) I don't like you. "Little greedy mind" gives more solid information; it says _two_ things about you yourself, just as @Nicole wrote.